# Why solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory cuts last letter of search term if protword file is empty?

Tags: solr

I have a solr schema that uses `solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory`. When I do admin/analysis
I see that for query "iphone", after `SnowballPorterFilterFactory` I get "iphon", even if the file specified in schema (*protwords_ro.txt*) is empty.

I have removed the filter and term text remains "iphone". Since my *protwords_ro.txt* file is empty I don't really need that filter right now, but I was wondering why is this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this filter is for stemming.

> In linguistic morphology and information retrieval, stemming is the process for reducing inflected (or sometimes derived) words to their stem, base or root form—generally a written word form

So for example for word resume this filter will give resum, etc.

Also,

> The Snowball stemmers rely on algorithms and considered fairly aggressive

I think this is the reason why you got `iphon`, even when your text file is empty.